# How can I send/receive IM Messages using python?

Tags: python, instant-messaging

How can I send/receive IM Messages using python? I want to send AOL Instant Messenger messages and receive them using python. I basically want to take in input from the chat, process it and then send the processed input back.

Comment: How about using http://www.imified.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code: http://code.google.com/p/madcow/source/browse/trunk/madcow/protocol/aim.py

Also:
http://www.gilesgoatboy.org/python/skippy.html

Generally, lots of examples can be found using a google search for: python aim